# Not correct show time (Daylight Saving Time)

Tags: time-date

Linux Mint 20.2

Emacs 27.2

Before 2 days (on 31 Oct) in our country **Daylight Saving Time Ended**.

```
When local daylight time was about to reach
Sunday, 31 October 2021, 03:00:00 clocks were turned backward 1 hour to
Sunday, 31 October 2021, 02:00:00 local standard time instead.
```

OS Linux Mint show current time 08:09 PM.
OK. This is a correct.

But on Emacs (mode-line) the time is 09:09 PM - it's incorrect.

In my init.el

```
(setenv "TZ" "GMT-3")
(display-time-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the time zone to `GMT-3`. This means it's 3 hours later than GMT all year round. This can't be correct if the place where you live has DST. Use the correct time zone name, for example `TZ=Europe/Kiev`. On Linux Mint, the system time zone name is in `/etc/timezone`.

It's really weird to set a time zone specifically for Emacs. Since your operating system has the correct time, just remove the setting of `TZ` for Emacs. (And if your OS didn't have the correct time, my advice would be to fix that.)